# How fit scrollview properly to screen

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, scrollview

I have question about scrollview. I look up on the internet but I couldn't fit any solution for it. I am using a windowed activity in my application. I use it without a problem until I add a scrollview. Scrollview isn't fit screen properly.

Here is the my activity code.

```
class ExtendedMedicineInfoActivity : Activity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityExtendedMedicineInfoBinding
var medicineUsageData = MedicineUsageData()
var gson = Gson()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityExtendedMedicineInfoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    medicineUsageData = gson.fromJson(intent.getStringExtra("medicineData"), MedicineUsageData::class.java)

    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
    val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val height = displayMetrics.heightPixels
    window.setLayout((width * .8).toInt(), (height * .8).toInt())
    val params = window.attributes
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    params.x = 0
    params.y = -20
    window.attributes = params
    setFields()
}

private fun setFields() {
    binding.expireDateEditText.setText(medicineUsageData.expireDate)
    binding.barcodeNumEditText.setText(medicineUsageData.barcodeNum)
    binding.companyNameEditText.setText(medicineUsageData.companyName)
    binding.drugSubstanceEditText.setText(medicineUsageData.drugSubstance)
    binding.medicineNameEditText.setText(medicineUsageData.productName)
    binding.partyNumEditText.setText(medicineUsageData.partyNum)
    binding.serialNumEditText.setText(medicineUsageData.serialNum)
}
}
```

This code doesn't produce any errors. I use it for my other windowed activities too. But this is the first time I try to add a scrollview to it.

Here is the xml code for this activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_medicine_list"
    tools:context=".ExtendedMedicineInfoActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/medicine_information"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clipToPadding="false"

        android:columnCount="1"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/medicine_name_text_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:hint="@string/medicine_name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/medicine_name_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Space />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/expire_date_text_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:hint="@string/expire_date">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/expire_date_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Space />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/company_name_text_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:hint="@string/company_name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/company_name_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Space />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/barcode_num_text_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:hint="@string/barcode_number">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/barcode_num_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Space />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/drug_substance_text_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:hint="@string/drug_substance">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/drug_substance_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Space />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/party_num_text_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:hint="@string/party_number">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/party_num_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Space />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/serial_num_text_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:hint="@string/serial_number">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/serial_num_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This code build and works without error. But this is the result.

[image: Upper side problem]

As you can see there is another element at the top but it doesn't show.

[image: Down side problem]

And there is redundant space under it.

I can fix upper problem by adding `android:layout_marginTop="56dp"` to inner GridLayout. But I know it isn't the best solution. Screen size can change or something else. And even if I add this line it doesn't fix my down side redundant space problem.

Can anyone help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. When I change my code values my problem is solved.

Here is the code which I changed.

```
window.setLayout((width * .8).toInt(), (height * .8).toInt())
val params = window.attributes
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
params.x = 0
params.y = -20
```

I changed it to this:

```
window.setLayout((width * .8).toInt(), (height * .9).toInt())
val params = window.attributes
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
params.x = 0
params.y = 100
```